# .NET Setting Thirdparty dll version dependencies with manifest file

Tags: .net, dll, manifest

I developed a .NET dll that depends on a third party dll with version 10.1.2 and has publickeytoken etc.
Now, this third party dll is release with new version 11.0. and i want to make use of this new version from my .net dll. I dont want to recompile against new version of third party dll. Instead can i have manifest xml file for my dll to dynamically define the third party dll version?

Is that the purpose of manifest files?

Comment: .NET doesn't use manifest files.  You can spin the wheel of fortune with a `<bindingRedirect>` in your app.exe.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, i added the following to app.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient"
                      publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91"
                      culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

And that took care.Thanks Hans.